# Which application permission should I add on Azure AD(Active Directory) so that users will visit the website without microsoft authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I removed all application permissions from the Graph API Directory but still all of the users from the active directory displays Microsoft login page. So which application permissions should I add to prevent a Microsoft login page?

Comment: You would need to remove Azure AD integration from your website so that it is no longer protected by Azure AD if you want your users to access the website without logging in first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @GauravMantri Instead of removing code can I add some flag set for applying azure AD integration?

Comment: AFAIK, No. If an application is protected by Azure AD, a user need to sign in to get access to the application.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you will see a Microsoft login screen if you use Azure AD.
If you want a more customized login screen for business-to-consumer scenarios, you can use [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html).